# A question related to interior points

Tags: real-analysis

### 1. Every point of the interval $(0, 1)$ is an interior point of that interval. Thus $(0, 1)^o = (0, 1)$.

### 2. Let $A = [a, b]$ where $a < b$. Then $A^o = (a, b)$.

I am trying to prove the $2^\text{nd}$ statement. The two problems above look almost identical. The difference is that an arbitrary element $x$ is assumed to be in  $(0, 1)$ in the $1^\text{st}$ one and $x$ is assumed to be in  $[a, b]$ in the $2^\text{nd}$. Does that make any difference?

Thanks.

Comment: The difference is the presence of the extremes of the interval. Show that $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ (or $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ in general) are not interior points.

Comment: If the second one had said "Let $A=[0,1]$.  Then $A^o=(0,1)$." then it would be the same problem as what you've got.  The difference between the two problems is NOT that $a$ and $b$ differ from $1$ and $0$.  Rather, it is the difference between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manuel's suggestion is right on the money: for any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ we have that

$$(a-\epsilon\,,\,a+\epsilon)\rlap{\;\,/}\subset [a,b]\implies a\;\;\text{is not an interior point}$$

and something similar for $\;b\;$ , so what you know about $\;(a,b)\;$ applies here...

Comment: So, the second problem is saying that every point in $[a, b]$ is an interior point. But the interior of $A$ doesn't contain $a$ and $b$, so for the second statement to be true, we additionally prove that $a$ and $b$ are not interior points, correct?

Comment: No, what the 2nd statement asks to prove, and Manuel hinted to, is that every point in $\;[a,b]\;$ is an interior one **except** $\;a,b\;$ , which makes the interior of $\;[a,b]\;$ *exactly* the same as that of $\;(a,b)\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the first result to prove the second. Just realize that you can 'scale' the interval $(0,1)$ to become any interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$. But you are looking at $[a,b]$. So show that neither $a$ nor $b$ can be interior points for $[a,b]$. Then all that is left of the interval is $(a,b)$, which so long as you give a convincing argument to as why this 'scaling' does not change the interior of an interval, you are done.

However, you don't have to do it this way since you can just as easily (if not more so) prove directly that the interior of $[a,b[$ is $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Just as yourself, given any point $c$ of $[a,b]$, can you find an open interval $(s,t)$ containing $c$ that is contained in $[a,b]$? Which is there no such interval for $a$ and $b$ but is for every $c \in [a,b]$ so long as $c \neq a$ and $c \neq b$? Knowing that, it is clear what the interior of $[a,b]$ is.